# Test Source Directories for Multi Dimension Flavors not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have an issue with test and androidTest source directories for multi-dimension flavors.

Given the following flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "taste", "serving"

productFlavors {
    chocolate {
        flavorDimension "taste"
    }
    strawberry {
        flavorDimension "taste"
    }
    kiwi {
        flavorDimension "taste"
    }
    sample {
        flavorDimension "serving"
    }
    whole {
        flavorDimension "serving"
    }
}
```

There are no issues with "non-test" source directories (of any flavor combination) being recognized in Android Studio:

*src/sample, src/whole, src/chocolate, src/strawberry, src/kiwi, 
src/chocolateSample, src/chocolateWhole, src/strawberrySample, src/strawberryWhole, src/kiwiSample, src/kiwiWhole*

My issue is with "test" source directories.
**Only *single dimension* flavors are recognized:** *src/testSample, src/testWhole, src/testChocolate, src/testStrawberry, src/testKiwi*.
**Multi-Dimension flavors are not:**  *src/testChocolateSample, src/testChocolateWhole, src/testStrawberrySample, src/testStrawberryWhole, src/testKiwiSample, src/testKiwiWhole*

This is also the case for the "androidTest" equivalent source directories.

I am under the impression that it is the app.iml which is not correctly generated.  While understanding that we should NEVER do this, the folders are correctly recognized if I were to manually add in the missing entries.

Why should this work with non-test source directories but fail with test source directories?  Is this a known issue or a limitation by the gradle plugin?

I tried researching this, but only found topics related single flavor dimensions for test source folders or mult-dimension flavors for non-test source folders.  There is nothing with regards to multi-dimension flavors for test source folders.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem somehow?

Comment: Answered in my post on GoogleGroups: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/Multi$20Flavor/adt-dev/1x2X-X2R1uk)

Comment: Yes.  Need to update your gradle to at least  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Comment: Hi, I am having the exact same issue now and I'm using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'. Do you have any ideea how it might work now?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to fix this by modifying your android app `build.gradle` file. For example, to add `testChocolateSample` to unit tests and `testChocolate` to android integration tests:

```
android {
    [...]
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
        testChocolateSample.java.srcDirs += 'src/testChocolateSample/java'
        androidTestChocolate.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTestChocolate/java'
    }
}
```

This also works for Kotlin. Just switch `java` with `kotlin`.